# Percentage in Reporting Services / Report Viewer

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a chart in a Report Viewer control:
[image]

Series data is a sum:
[image]

**Problem** How to make the Redemptions axis into a percentage?  eg 5am has 45% of the total redemptions for that day

Comment: Can you describe your dataset in some detail.  Depending on the structure, you might be able to get away with using the existing dataset and not write any new SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing your data, i'm going to guess that you'll probably have to do an aggregate of each day's Redemtpions, then join that to each time period.

so, without knowing your data or anything, here's an example:

```
 ;with dayavg as
(
    select day, count(*) as NumberRedemptionsDay
    from dbo.Redepmtions
    group by day
),
houravg as
(
    select day, hour, count(*) as NumberRedeptionsHour
    from dbo.Redemptions
    group by day, hour
)
select
    houravg.hour,
    houravg.NumberRedeptionsHour,
    (houravg.NumberRedeptionsHour/NumberRedemptionsDay)*100 as Perc
from houravg
    inner join dayavg
        on houravg.day=dayavg.day
```

Comment: Many thanks - I thought there may be an easy way to do it in RS.. but this is great.